# My animation doesn't start, when I try in unity. Why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a gun in unity for fun, and I have worked on it a lot, but now I need to make the animations. But I cant seem to figure out why it doesn't work. Here is all the pictures that should be needed to solve the problem.[image: The script were I want to start it] [image: The AnimatorThe components and deck]

I have tried watching many tutorials on it, but none worked. I tried adding the animator to the mesh only and running it through 2 scripts, that didn't work either. I expect it to play the firing animation when pressing left mouse button (left mouse button press activates ShootBullet()).

Comment: SO is not a fan of pictures of code as it cant be searched or copied and pasted.

Answer (score 2):

Your animation is not attached to anything. The "New State" Animation is your base state, and you need to connect the "g18_rig" animation to the "New State" Animation. Right Click on the "New State" Animation and create an arrow and connect it to your "g18_rig" animation.

Also, I would recommend to create a boolean parameter and play the animation based on that, rather than grabbing the animation component and playing the animation clip.

You could first get the Animator Component, and then use the SetBool function.

Comment: this is the right answer.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to attach the animation clip(g18_rig|g18_firing) to the new state but it doesn't work, I tried to look a bit better and change the speed on the animation, and I can see it fires at the start if that helps. Also if you have a video on how to play animations using Booleans I would love to see it.

Comment: While the game is running, you should be able to go to the animation tab to see if the animation is playing. Based on your description, your animation is indeed working, but it might be an error in the code that is preventing the animation from fully playing. This video shows how to set up boolean parameters and settings for the animation. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FF6kezDQZ7s

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the layer name with the animation string. Not used Animator.Play() for a long time. But I think the string should be "Base Layer.g18_rig|g18_firing"